# Query to get the data at particular time

Tags: oracle, join

I need to write a query for attendance, which gives the attendance for current time and previous 10 minutes. In total 20 records.
I have the below query. it gives me the correct data for current time. But the previous attendance goes on reducing.
For example : at 12:30 PM the attendance is 2000. But when the time reaches 1:30 PM the attendnce corresponding to 12:30 shows very less.

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR (each_sec, 'HH24:MI') p_time, COUNT (each_sec) cnt
FROM (SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT d.userid, d.logdate
                FROM atendance_data d
                     JOIN
                     (SELECT   userid, MAX (logdate) logdate
                          FROM atendance_data
                         WHERE TRUNC (logdate) = TRUNC (SYSDATE)
                      GROUP BY userid) m
                     ON d.userid = m.userid AND d.logdate = m.logdate
               WHERE d.c1 NOT IN ('Check-Out', 'Break-Out')) c
             JOIN
             (SELECT     SYSDATE + (1 - LEVEL) / 24 / 3600 * 600 each_sec
                    FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20) s ON  c.logdate <= s.each_sec
             )
 GROUP BY each_sec
   ORDER BY each_sec
```

I have to write a where condition to take maximum of logdate, saying less than each_sec. I guess that is where i am going wrong. But I dont know how to do it.

Can anyone help me doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe your table and provide test data, please. Without that nobody can help you.

Comment: what is the interval of checking time ????

Answer (score 0):

I have got it done like this. Thank you all for your responses

```
SELECT   COUNT (*), each_sec
FROM (SELECT a.userid, a.logdate, a.c1, each_sec
        FROM atendance_data a,
             (SELECT   userid, MAX (logdate) logdate, each_sec
                  FROM (SELECT userid, logdate, c1, each_sec
                          FROM (SELECT a.USERID,A.LOGDATE,A.C1, b.each_sec
                                  FROM atendance_data a
                                       JOIN
                                       (SELECT       SYSDATE
                                                   +   (1 - LEVEL)
                                                     / 24
                                                     / 3600
                                                     * 600 each_sec
                                              FROM DUAL
                                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20) b
                                       ON a.logdate <= b.each_sec
                                     AND trunc(a.logdate) =trunc(sysdate)                                                                 
                                       ))
              GROUP BY userid, each_sec) b
       WHERE a.userid = b.userid
         AND a.logdate = b.logdate
         AND Trunc (a.logdate) = trunc(sysdate))
WHERE c1 NOT IN ('Check-Out', 'Break-Out')
GROUP BY each_sec 
ORDER  BY each_sec;
```